# Want to add a Form field in Admin along with Model fields in django

Tags: python, django

I want to add 3 fields in my Admin.py page. out of which two fields are from Model.py and one field is from form.py. But somehow when i add these fields to admin.site.register function, an error pops up saying 'userlist' is not recognizable. Below is my code :

Models.py

```
class About(models.Model):
    about_author = models.TextField()
    pic = models.FileField(upload_to = '', default = 'static/defaul.jpg')
```

Form.py

```
class PostAuthorDetails(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(PostAuthorDetails,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['userlist'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = About
        fields = '__all__'
```

Admin.py

```
class PostAuthorDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostAuthorDetails

    def get_fieldsets(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return((None,{'fields':('about_author','pic','userlist'),}),)

admin.site.register(About,PostAuthorDetailsAdmin)
```

Please advise whats wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

FormFields are class members. You can not declare FormFields during the initialisation of the Form.

```
class PostAuthorDetails(forms.ModelForm):
    userlist = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = About
        '__all__'
```

See the docs about ModelForms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you out. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as the correct answer. :)